# Integrate OAuth2 - Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to integrate OAuth 2 into my project so that I can use the UBER API. Unfortunately every framework/installation method I have tried does not work. I'm using Swift 2 and Xcode 7 so I'm not sure if this would be the problem.

Each framework/project I have downloaded has files missing which prevents it from running.

Does anyone know how to integrate OAuth 2 into a Swift 2/Xcode 7 project?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that the sample projects which you are running are not using cocoapods, because if they do, you need to open the project using .workspace file. if you will try to open using project file it won't compile

Comment: Yes, they are using cocoapods. Do I just follow the same steps for installation except using the workspace file instead? i.e. Add files to project > OAuth2.xcworkspace

Comment: sample project is not compiling or when you add files in your project, it gives error?

Comment: It's not compiling when I add the project/framework to my exisiting project

Comment: don't add files from sample sample project, use cocoapods for that. can you send the link where installation process is written?